# Allow only 1 IP which can access ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .htaccess

I have created new ASP.NET website. I´m editing in in Visual Studio (Open WebSite and via FTP). I want to block everyone from viewing website except my IP adress.

In PHP I was doing it in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XX$ //my IP

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/construct

RewriteRule (.*) /construct/index.php [R=307,L] //redirect when other IP access website
```

In ASP.NET I have only found this solution (in Web.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <add ipAddress="XXX.XXX.X.X" allowed="true"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this doesn´t work for me. When I enter page after writing this it gives me following error:

*Error while serving request.
Server didn't return any web site which can be shown.
Probable cause of problem is in script which generates this web page.*

What is the problem or how else can I solve this?

Comment: you application is asp.net or php ?

Comment: Have you gone through [this checklist](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) on the server? Assuming you have, can you verify the IP your client (your machine) is using matches the restriction you configured?

Comment: In asp.net and it doesnt run on my own server but i´ve paid hosting so i cannot configure server.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue caused because the IP and Domain Restrictions Role is not installed on the server. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this any one and store one string variable

```
string ip=HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString(); 
or 
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
or
string ip=HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
```

//Then check the ip address was matched . if true ,then allowed to access your code

```
if(ip=="xxx.xxx.xx.x")//Your IP address 
{
//your code is here 

}
```

Comment: I have solved it by adding this on masterpage and redirectig everything except my ip adress on special page. I think it is good temporary solution if someone cannot configure server. Thanks for the idea.